# Is there any disposable email service that allows receiving verification emails at a temporary address?

Tags: qa-developer

Is there any disposable email service that allows receiving verification emails at a temporary address that self-destructs after 24 hours so that it will be helpful in automation of 'customer registration and verification' test case?

Comment: Are you testing locally ? why not set up a local mail server for internal use ?

Comment: One caveat, some third-party service providers disallow the use of disposable email providers. Apple is one example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes in the current scenario we have so many disposable email service providers available in the market. they provide the free public and private inbox for a temporary email address. recently I found some very good disposable email service providers and one of them is https://mail7.io.

```java
import org.apcahe.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;

public class mail7{

    private static final String EMAIL-DOMAIN = ‘mail.io’;
    private static final String EMAIL_APIKEY = ‘mail7_api_key’;
    private static final String EMAIL_APISecret = ‘mail7_api_secret’;
    private String emailid;
    
    public usernameGenerator(){
    
    String username = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(8).toLowerCase();
    System.out. println(“Random Username is ” + username);
    return username;
}

public getInbox(String username){

    HttpResponse <String> httpResponse = Unirest.get(“"https://api.mail7.io/inbox?apikey=" + EMAIL_APIKEY + "&apisecret=" + EMAIL_APISecret + "&to=" + username”)
.asString();
    System.out.println( httpResponse.getHeaders().get("Content-Type"));
    System.out.println(httpResponse.getBody());
    return httpResponse.getBody();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

With Gmail [the sender can](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html) add a `+` and any combination of words or numbers after your email address and you'll still receive the email.

> if your [address is] hikingfan@gmail.com, you could send mail to hikingfan+friends@gmail.com or hikingfan+mailinglists@gmail.com.

So you can potentially get by with only a single Gmail email address and you can check the recipient of received emails to see which test it corresponds to.

Of course [Gmail has an API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api) with which you can programmatically receive emails, if required (or you can potentially [use regular POP](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7104828?hl=en)).

It appears you can also [set up a filter to automatically delete old emails](https://yourbusiness.azcentral.com/automatically-delete-old-messages-gmail-16193.html).

If you don't want to use Gmail: While other providers might not support the exact same functionality, they may support something similar. I would start by checking whether something like this exists with whichever provider your company is using as their primary email provider or if a rule could be set up to achieve something like this.

---

The other option, as mentioned in the comments, would be to **set up a local mail server** on whichever machine the test is run or have a test mail server that's either permanently running on your local network or that's created as part of the test process.

Minimising or avoiding external dependencies in tests is always a good thing to strive towards. You don't want your tests to fail or to be unable to test if some external service has downtime. Or they could make a change that breaks your tests. There's also always the risk of confidential or private data accidentally ending up in a test. If you're sending that data to some untrusted third party, that could be quite a problem (even if they pinky promise to keep your data secure and delete it after 24 hours).

Comment: on gmail . in the before the @ are ignored (common scam with subscribe account). So my.name@gmail.com is the same as myname@gmail.com, m.yname@gmail.com and so on

Answer (score 3):

Following options are quite good too. Have been using them for quite some time:

1. **Mailinator.com**
2. **Guerrilla Mail**
3. **Mailsac**
4. **Mailtrap**

For creating mailboxes during manual testing, we use mailinator whereas in automation tests, if there is email communication involved and we have to read certain email content as part of tests (as is the case with you), we use guerrillmail. In our case, we have to read verification codes sent in emails and on some occasions, we have to validate certain links sent in emails.

Answer (score 2):

If you search online, you will get many services which provide free temporary email.

Here are a few examples,

https://temp-mail.org/en/

https://mail.tm/en/

https://www.emailondeck.com/

---

Apart from this you can also use **Gmail**.

Google allows to append `+<number>` to your ID and send emails to the same inbox as the actual email address.

For example, if your email address is jhondoe@gmail.com, then you can send an email to

- jhondoe+1@gmail.com
- jhondoe+2@gmail.com
- jhondoe+3@gmail.com
- .
- .
- .
- jhondoe+n@gmail.com

All the emails will be sent to the jhondoe@gmail.com inbox.

Now, you may be concerned about disposing of the test emails.

Well, for that you can set a filter in your gmail to send those test emails to your Trash folder. Google automatically deletes all emails older than 30 days. This much time would be sufficient for you to verify that the emails were actually delivered and have the correct information and format.

Answer (score 1):

For manual testing, I've used [**10 Minute Mail**](https://10minutemail.com/), which (like the name says), self-destructs the email address after 10 minutes.

Depending on how you're automating the signup process, it may not work for your case but the option is there if you need it.

Comment: Someone proposed an edit which changed the URL of the service I linked. I have overridden the approval of that edit - despite sharing similar names it is not the same service. That edit should've been a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

## If the service is free, you pay with your data.

For any professional purpose, you should **seriously** think about what kind of mail service provider you are using, and what kind of contract you have with them.

- Running your own mail server is an option, but it leaves your admin staff to run something they're not specialized in.
- Alternatively, outsource that task to an external provider. Someone with a Service Level Agreement.

Answer (score 0):

There are many, just search in google using "temporary email id"
fews are below:

https://temp-mail.org/en/
https://tempail.com/en/

Answer (score 0):

I recently learned about yopmail. We used it for manual testing.  You can use [any_name_you_want]@yopmail.com, e.g me@yopmail.com or michael@yopmail.com

It will display any messages sent to that address *publically* and *from anyone who uses the email address*  so expect to see other peoples work for commonly used emails.  An example is shown below with a common address (junk@yopmail.com) used by many.

[image]

Whereas noone else has currently used michaeldurrant

[image]