# How can I automate the email signup and verification process using selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, email, nightwatchjs

I have to automate the email signup and verification process using selenium.
Any suggestion?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any disposable email service that allows receiving verification emails at a temporary address?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/44861/is-there-any-disposable-email-service-that-allows-receiving-verification-emails)  Make use of temp mails and their API's to automate the process

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Do you want to create emails on your product? Do you want to create checks for the UI through which the users create emails? These are two completely different problems.

Comment: Actually I am looking forward to find a solution for creating disposable emails on my product for testing purpose.